# Bootstrap uneven columns order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, I have three columns with varying heights. The middle column is the shortest. My problem is, as the screen size reduces, the right column is simply sliding under the middle column. What I would like for it to do is slide all the way to the left.

To explain further: 
When used on a phone, I want column A and column B to be side by side (with a column width of 6) and I want column C to line up under column A. As the screen gets larger, I want all the columns to be on the same line next to each other.

Here is my sample code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <div>Column B</div>
            <div>Column B</div>
            <div>Column B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using push and pull, but I can't get it to work right. I'm only assuming it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do. Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Grids should add up to twelve like so: http://jsfiddle.net/M43Pn/1/

Comment: I know grids are composed of 12. Maybe I'm using the grid funcitonality completely wrong, but with the exception of this little inconvenience, I have been able to get all of my screen sizes to display how I want them using this method above. (By going over 12 for the smaller screen sizes, the columns automatically wrap and appear below the ones on the left. Essentially just making my layouts appear vertically instead of horizontally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I tweaked Buck's answer. You have to add the clearfix div before the last column, but make sure it is hidden for the medium display.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>
            <div>Column A</div>

        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <div>Column B</div>
            <div>Column B</div>
            <div>Column B</div>
        </div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
            <div>Column C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you to all of you for taking time to help me out!

Answer (score 3):

The grid system works in a way that each row has 12 columns. You are going beyond 12 columns through your HTML. More specifically, you can see this in your `col-xs-6` class being in every column, which actually amounts to 18, not 12. In other words, just make sure that all columns inside of a single row, add up to 12. Take a look at the below, revised HTML to get an idea:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>Column A</div>
        <div>Column A</div>
        <div>Column A</div>
        <div>Column A</div>
        <div>Column A</div>
        <div>Column A</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>Column B</div>
        <div>Column B</div>
        <div>Column B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>Column C</div>
        <div>Column C</div>
        <div>Column C</div>
        <div>Column C</div>
        <div>Column C</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Just adjust the columns and make sure you are adding up to 12. Also, you can find more information on the grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M43Pn/2/)**

Comment: If I reduce the xs screen size to a column width of 4, then I'm not achieving what I want to do. On xs screen sizes, I want column A and column B to be next to each other, each taking up half the width of the screen. I don't want all three columns displayed horizontally on an xs screen. That would be smashed smaller than I would like.

Comment: Then you need to effectively fix the grid to the way you want it. It sounds like you want Columns A & B to be on one row on a xs screen and have Column C be on the row below it?

Comment: Yes, I want Columns A&B to be on one row for an xs screen and then Column C on the next row below. **However**, for a medium and up screen, I want all three columns to be next to each other. Maybe you can't do both without getting really deep into Less or something along those lines? (I'm not ready to start that yet.)

Answer (score 0):

what about if you change

`<div class="pull-left col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">`
to

`<div class="pull-left col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-2">`

Comment: This will cause the current div to take up that entire row at the small screen size. This may not be what they want because it would shift two of the rows.

Comment: Here is an example of your above code: http://jsfiddle.net/M43Pn/3/ but instead of the small screen, i did it for the extra small.

Comment: BB is right, that causes the column to take up the whole screen and that's not what I want either.

Answer (score 0):

As BuddhistBeast said, you only have about 12 columns to work with, so you need to figure out a way to divide them up into whatever portion you so desire.

As for aligning Column C under Column A, since Bootstrap automatically puts it under Column B due to it having less content, and therefore more space (an easy fix would be to add more content to B), you are probably going to have to use the **clearfix** class to realign:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

You can find more about it here. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2NyC6/1/) I just made up to my understanding of what you would like to see.

Comment: This forces column C to always be on the left, which I don't want either. I know rows are only supposed to be in increments of 12, but as I mentioned, I actually really like how columns will wrap if you go above 12. Maybe its bad practice, but I like how bootstrap lets me display horizontally on a big screen and then automatically switch to a vertical layout on small screens. I thought that was one of the major perks of using Bootstrap? (I'm very new to it.)